# jQuery - if at least one of the elements has class DON'T proceed with function

Tags: jquery, class, element

So I have a list of elements with same classes and I want jQuery to know, if at least one of the elements **hasClass('invalid')** TO NOT execute function, so all elements shouldn't have a class in order for jQuery to proceed.

I've tried with **each** function but in that case, if only one of the elements doesn't have a class, he's good to go, and I need for all elements to NOT have a class **.invalid**.

For example, if a list like this has at least of class **.invalid**, jQuery shouldn't do anything and if all classes are without that class **.invalid** (else) than do something.

```
<p class="someElement">1</p>
<p class="someElement">2</p>
<p class="someElement invalid">3</p>
<p class="someElement">4</p>
<p class="someElement">5</p>
<p class="someElement">6</p>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (!selector.hasClass('invalid')) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have the elements in a variable, your `.hasClass` approach is almost correct because that function *determines whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class*:

If it returns `true` if any one or more does, then it'll return `false` if *none* do, so simple boolean negation will match that case:

```
var elementList = $('p.someElement');

if (!elementList.hasClass('invalid')) {
    // none of the elements had that class
}
```

Comment: I like that, but will go with Taplar's method, simple filter function solves it simply enough, but thank for your solution!

Comment: Personally I would probably go with the hasClass approach.  `filter()` is a generic function which has to consider any input that it could be given in order to get the result, where as `hasClass()` is specifically checking the class, so there may be some performance gain there.  Most likely unnoticable, but most likely more performant.

Comment: @DearBee your call - the `.filter` method works for more complicated selectors, but you'd already identified `.hasClass` yourself and it's actually simpler than a `.length < 1` test.

Comment: Yeah, I had to revisit this, definitely better solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
//use filter to check if any element matches a case
if ($('.someElement').filter('.invalid').length < 1) {
    //do stuff
}

//or hasClass as it loops as part of it's logic
// https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.hasClass
if (!$('.someElement').hasClass('.invalid')) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: @DearBee it's not actually necessary - the `.hasClass()` that you already know about tells you if _any one or more_ elements in the set have that class, so `! $('.someElement').hasClass('invalid')` will tell you if _none_ do.

Comment: You don't even need filter. Just `$('.someElement.invalid').length < 1` will work

Comment: ^ provided he doesn't already have the elements stored in a variable.

Comment: And yeah it looks like hasClass does loop inside it's logic.  https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.hasClass

Comment: indeed - from the docs for `.hasClass` : _"Determine whether **any of the matched elements** are assigned the given class"_ (my emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

Well... why not looking if elements do have the class?
For what you said if you have only one that have the class you don't hant to execute the function so, in that case a boolean will do.

If one of the elements have the class invalid just return false and after it verify if false or true to execute the said function.

Hope I could help.

Happy coding =}

Comment: whilst technically correct, this style of answer is not particularly useful because it's verbose and chatty but has no code.   (not my downvote, BTW)

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for the input. When I did answer the question didn't have any code, so I just write the logic to do so. But I will have you comment in attention next time I answer something. Thanks again